# How can I group A horizontal Results set into a vertical one like below:

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2012, pivot

```
Select * from Machines Where DayOfWeight = '2013-10-31'
```

RETURNS

```
MachineId   TotalValue  DayOfWeigh
1           290.70      2013-10-31
2           647.20      2013-10-31 
3           2178.56     2013-10-31
```

How can I get it to return:

```
DayOfWeigh  1       2       3
2013-10-31  290.70  647.20  2178.56
```

This seems quite simple, but I cant find the right grouping statement or pivot perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from machines
pivot (sum(TotalValue) for MachineID in ([1],[2],[3])) p
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: This returns the right column headings: Dayofweigh, 1,2,3

But there are 3 rows returned, with 2 null values in each.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DayOfWeigh ,MachineId, TotalValue
    FROM MachineTotals
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(TotalValue)
    FOR MachineId IN ([1], [2], [3)
)AS p
```